# Suppress the 'press any key to continue' in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script. After a stage in the command window it says 'press any key to continue' and halts, and after something is pressed the script continues. How can I prevent this in the script?

Comment: Could we see the source code ? :/

Comment: This question doesn't specify if you want to avoid the text or the stopping of the script. @Silly's answer will hide the text, @user1066231's answer will cause the script will not stop and wait. This could actually also be achieved by `pause<nul`, which looks similar to `pause>nul` but has different result

Answer (score 9):

That's the output of the `PAUSE` command:

http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html

The problem with PAUSE is that it's often necessary when you run a batch file from Windows explorer (or you cannot read the output) but it's annoying in the command prompt. I asked about it here and I was suggested a nifty trick:

[Conditional PAUSE (not in command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934619/conditional-pause-not-in-command-line/3938027#3938027)

Answer (score 8):

Pause>nul Will make it not echo 'press any key to continue . . .'

Comment: Brilliant! And since PAUSE seems to wait too long I now use this :

  `timeout /t 1 >nul`

Answer (score 2):

you can call other script like this from source, `@echo | call otherScript.bat`
please find the detailed answer here [Another thread with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583565/how-to-skip-pause-in-batch-file)