# Batch file runs other batch files without press key

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have one batch file which runs multiple batch files. I use the CALL statement in this file. But after execution one batch file I have to press any key to run other batch file. Is there any posibility how to disable this condition to press any key after call every single batch?

P.S. I need "press any key" when I run single batch.

There is an example of the main batch file

```
 @echo off
 echo This batch runs all scripts
 CALL A.bat 
 CALL B.bat 
 CALL C.bat
```

Comment: remove the `pause` command. If there is none, show (relevant part of) your code.

Comment: look into this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552648/suppress-the-press-any-key-to-continue-in-batch-script

Comment: @Stephan I got this batch ->  http://www.pastebin.com/63jgBHvU

Comment: that script won't give you "press any key". Take a look into the called scripts.,

Comment: I got pause in these batch files. But I need that pause when I run batches individually. But when I Run this batch, I don´t want to press a key.

Comment: Include your code into the question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40399475/edit) your post! Links may become invalid in future, and some users might not have access privileges to certain external resources...

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you (probably) have a `pause` command in each of the called scripts. Remove them.

If you are not allowed to modify these scripts (or it doesn't make sense to modify them because they are created dynamically), you can fake an `ENTER` by piping an `echo` to the scripts:

```
echo/|call A.bat
echo/|call B.bat
echo/|call C.bat
```

`echo/` will just output a `CRLF` (= `ENTER` = empty line)
`|` will give the output of the left command as input to the right command.

Note: this will give an `ENTER` to the first command in the scripts, that expect some input. If you're lucky, it's the `pause` command.

**edit** to match your recent comment to the question:

when you can edit your `a.bat` etc, you can replace the `pause` command there with this line:

```
echo %cmdcmdline%|find /i " CALL " >nul || pause
```

This checks, if the script was `call`ed and only executes the `pause`, when not.

`%cmdcmdline%` contains the exact way, how the script was being executed.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. Thank You!

Comment: added something you'll probably like `;)`

Answer (score -1):

Use Pause>null to suppress the 'Press any key to continue.' message.

http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html

Comment: this only suppresses the message. There is still need to press any key.

Comment: Make some echo before pause is one solution@echo Hello World

Comment: after pause (not before)

Comment: @SirAlex Could You be please more specific? You can see my batch in this link -> http://pastebin.com/63jgBHvU